# visualization regarding triple integration problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I think our readers here may also have had this query when they initially began triple integration. Query is, in double integration we have double integration of a function (f) over an area / dxdy . and here the function is considered as the height or the third dimension which we can comfortably visualize. And if function is scalar 1 it's just the area of the plane surface . Now in case of triple integration if f is scalar 1 then we get the volume. But if (f) is not a scalar function then what dimension would we consider f to be with respect to the volume element dV / dxdydz.can someone give a good visualisation for a starter to have a good base about triple integration  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualize the f(x) in a triple integration as the curve satisfying points having the same temperature.